# how to define a variable in PHP, to get the value from a function on a different PHP class?

Tags: php, yii

i have php script:

```
<?php
    echo CHtml::textArea('application_log', $applicationLog = '', array(
       'id'  => 'application_log_id',
       'rows'    => 20,
       'cols'    => 128,
    )); 
?>
```

its defined in my `_tab3.php`, in my controler I have a function :

```
public function actionLog()
    {
        $applicationLog  = '';
        // get the filter value to show max lines
        $showMaxLines    = (int) $this->getAppRequest()->getParam('log_show_max_lines', 50);

        try
        {
            foreach ($this->getLogData($showMaxLines) as $log)
            {
                $applicationLog .= $log;
            }
        }
        catch (CHttpException $ex)
        {
            $this->getWebUser()->setFlash('error', 'Error: ' . $ex->getMessage());
        }

        $this->render('log', array(
            'applicationLog' => $applicationLog,
            'showMaxLines'   => $showMaxLines,
            // 'log_show_max_lines' is a placeholder for the js value in the template
        ));
    }
```

`$applicationLog` in my `_tab3.php` should be the same as in my `actionLog()` function. however it is defined like this : `$applicationLog = ''` and I dont kow how can I get it to be the same as in the function `actionLog()`. I am working with YII framework and I am faily new to this. thanks.

here is my [_tab3.php](http://pastebin.com/5gTKTDhY).

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You are setting `$applicationLog` to `''` before passing it into the function.
2. Your are not passing `$applicationLog` into the partial views.

You are passing `$applicationLog` from the controller to the `_log` view correctly.

However, since `_tab3` is a partial view, `$applicationLog` needs to be forwarded to the view. If you had a partial view `_my_partial_view`, you would do this be passing it in an array as the second variable of `renderPartial`.

```
$this->renderPartial('_my_partial_view', array('applicationLog' => $applicationLog));
```

`$applicationLog` needs to be passed on like this in all partial views until where it is used.

Lastly, remove the assignment and it should be fine.

```
echo CHtml::textArea('application_log', $applicationLog, array(...
```

Comment: when I remove that I get undefined variable. `Undefined variable: applicationLog`

Comment: I just noticed your view is not the same one being called in `render`. Is `_tab3` a partial view in `log`?

Comment: i have this in my `index.php` : `
$log = $this->renderPartial('_tab_log', null, $return=true); ` and its followed by ` $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs',array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'Log'=>array('content'=>$log, 'id'=>'log'),
    ),

));` I am not what do u mean by "view is not the same one being called in render", I have been uing Yii from 2 weeks now and I am not sure what u r asking me. thanks

Comment: Ok. First, please edit your question to include the contents of `_tab_log.php`

Comment: I used a different name here but my ` _tab_log.ph ` is the same as ` _tab3.php ` i just used a different name here. but in my files is correct. I have just included the ` _tab3.php ` content here. I hope it helps.

Comment: I edited my tab3.php I added ` $this->renderPartial('_my_partial_view', array('applicationLog' => $applicationLog));
 ` right after the function starts, I removed the assignment and when I run I got the error.